# SplitView Navigation Issue for detail View in Ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I try implement the `spliviewcontroller` in iPad app. In my masterTable has 10 rows & each one navigate to different detail view through master Table row selection like "Setting" in iPad.

I search a lot but didn't find anything which has functionality like this.

I got the code from here : [RayWenderLich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29469/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uisplitview-tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to change `viewControllers` property to set a specific ViewController for DetailViewConroller of SplitViewController, when user taps the row.

```
AppDel.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[navigationController, detailViewController];
```

where splitViewController is a property of AppDelegate:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) YourSplitViewController *splitViewController;
```

and `YourSplitViewController` is a subclass of `UISplitViewController`.

And where AppDel is a `define`:

```
#define AppDel ((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)
```